# error: no match for 'operator=='

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm having some trouble implementing a search function for a Linked List using base code from [this data structures book](http://people.cs.vt.edu/~shaffer/Book/). This is the error I'm getting:

```
llist.h: In member function 'void LList<E>::search(const E&, bool&) [with E = Int]':
Llistmain.cpp:31:1:   instantiated from here
llist.h:119:3: error: no match for 'operator==' in '((LList<Int>*)this)->LList<Int>::curr->Link<Int>::element == value'
```

And here is the implementation of my search member function:

```
void search(const E& value, bool& found) {
    if (curr->element == value)
        found = true;
    else if (curr != NULL) {
        curr = curr->next;
        search(value, found);
    }
    else found = false;
}
```

Why am I getting an error about the `== operator`? Both `curr->element` and `value` are of type Int. Should I be checking for equality differently?

Answer (score 1):

Does your type `Int` have a comparision operator? If it has, does it take both of its arguments as `const`? In particular, if you comparision operator is a member it is easy to forget to make it a `const` member:

```
bool Int::operator== (Int const& other) const {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This solved it. I whipped up an overloaded comparison operator for Int and problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, `element` is not an `int` but a `Link<Int>`. You need to get the `Int` out of the `Link` and turn it into something that has an `operator==` (note that `Int` is not `int`).